# Javascript matching to see if an email or phone number has been supplied

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a contact form with a text area input only field, which allows the end user to fill out and include a method on how to be contacted. They can choose to enter an email, phone number or both within their message.

I am using jQuery along with javascript to process the form and check if a contact method has been inputted into the message. Here is what I have and it is not getting the job done. Am I doing my matching on the value correctly?

```
var error = ''
if (value == '' || value == 'Fill out this form and include an email or phone number to be contacted ...') {
    error = 'A message along with your contact details are required before sending.';
}
else if (!value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/) || !value.match(/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]+$/)) {
    error = 'Your message should contain an email address or phone number.';
}
```

The first error checking works, the 2nd keeps giving an error even if I do enter an email or phone number or both into the message. Should I be breaking this apart and searching each word individually is that how you do it?

Comment: Try `value.match...[regex]` instead of `!value.match...[regex]`.

Comment: Not for nothing, but why would you want to torture yourself (or whoever you're building this form for) by allowing the user to put their contact info anywhere in the message?  Wouldn't it be easier just to go the standard route and have one or two separate contact fields?

Comment: To answer your question, it is quite simple. So many users feel threaten when you ask for a number or an email in a form - some prefer one or other never both. I been using this on my own site for over a year and never had an issue. Actually I get more request on my properties. I am now upgrading it the Flash Form to a Regular Form with Java scripting and like to keep the same formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here, some of which have been pointed out by the other answerers.

Here is a solution which I have found to work:

```
if (value == '' || value == 'Fill out this form and include an email or phone number to be contacted ...') {
    error = 'A message along with your contact details are required before sending.';
}
else if (value.search(/(\s|^)[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(\s|$)/) == -1 && value.search(/(\s|^)(?:\([2-9]\d{2}\)\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:\-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}(\s|$)/) == -1) {
    error = 'Your message should contain an email address or phone number.';
}
```

Search does indeed solve the problem however it is critical that you modify the beginning and end of string delimiters (`^` and `$`) from your RegExs.  These would only match their respective targets if they were the only thing in the string being tested.  What you want is to find emails and phones as distinct tokens (aka separated from other text by whitespace).

To that end, I've changed the beginning and end delimiters to be `(\s|^)` and `(\s|$)`.  These say that the match must have both leading and trailing whitespaces, or be at the beginning or end of the string being matched. This will ensure that you can have phones and emails in your string, and not match something like "adfasdfexample@example.comasdfadfa"

Another problem I found was that the phone number RegEx you were using was not sufficient.  It was too greedy, and would match a group of numbers with letters in between them.  I've replaced it with another RegEx that is significantly more robust.

Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/T9guw/2/

Comment: This one works as well, seems to be faster. Sweet! and Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the `^` tells regex that is the beginning of the match & the `$` indicated the end. `value.match` is trying to match the whole string. you should try changing it to :

```
if(value.search(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/) != -1 && value.search(/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]+$/) != -1){
error = 'Your message should contain an email address or phone number.'
}
```

also your if statement is basically saying: If there is NO Email OR there is NO Phone return an error. changing `||` to `&&` will make it: If there is NO Email AND there is NO Phone return an error.

Comment: I tried your method search. It processes the form when a message is inserted and doesn't contain a contact method as well as when one is supplied. I never used search before and will Google it to see what I can find. This does look promising.

Answer (score 1):

Your boolean logic in the second if is incorrect. Currently you are saying that the input must match BOTH to be valid because currently if either match fails, the whole expression fails. You want to change the || to && in the second if.

```
var error = '' 
if (value == '' || value == 'Fill out this form and include an email or phone number to be contacted ...') { 
    error = 'A message along with your contact details are required before sending.'; 
} 
else if (!value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/) && !value.match(/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]+$/)) { 
    error = 'Your message should contain an email address or phone number.'; 
}
```

I did not check the validity of the patterns themselves, but a phone number no longer resulted in an error.

Comment: Tried both || and && it works if I just enter a phone number or email. But it doesn't work when I include a message as well.

The option I am looking for is to include just one input field where you enter a message along with contact method and search to see if it was supplied.

Comment: The other answer combined with this answer should help, you need to remove the ^ from beginning and & from end of patterns because those enforce "startsWith" "endsWith"

Comment: Perfect! That solved the issue. By using - (!value.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}/) && !value.match(/[0-9\-\(\)]+/)) Thanks.